# Trying to install WIndows on the same disk as Windows installation media

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, bootloader, mbr, windows-installation

I know I can just use a pen drive but that will take a bit of time and I am impatient, so is there any way I can install Windows on my HDD without a pen drive?

The machine is an ASUS laptop and it has 2 disks, an SSD and a 1TB HDD. Linux Mint is installed on the SSD, and I've downloaded the Windows ISO file in my /home directory.

I used WoeUSB-ng to install the Windows installation media from the ISO to the HDD, and doing that leaves the HDD with 3 partitions, as I see it on the Disks gui:

- 4.2 MB free space
- 1.0 TB NTFS/exFAT/HPFS partition named "NTFS"
- 1.0 MB W95 FAT16 (LBA) partition named "UEFI_NTFS"

in that order.

Rebooting my system and entering the BIOS shows UEFI_NTFS as a bootable partition, and booting into it loads the Windows installation media.

Once on there, I see the HDD as one of the disk options, however Windows tells me that:

"the disk is formatted as MBR and Windows can only be installed on a GPT partitioned disk"

So I go back to Linux mint and use the Disks gui to format the HDD as GPT, but reinstalling the Windows installation media using WoeUSB-ng converts it back to MBR.

Maybe there is some software other than WoeUSB-ng that installs the Windows installation media with GPT partitioning? Or is there a way I can create a small 15gb partition just for the Windows installation media, install it there, format the rest of the disk as GPT and then boot into the installation media to install Windows on another partition?

Or is none of this actually possible?

Comment: No way - a disk is either entirely GPT or not.

Comment: In order to accomplish this you will need two disks.  Create a partition that is large enough to contain the contents of the ISO.  Use the secondary drive to install Windows to the unallocated partition.  The first drive should be GPT in order for Windows to be installed in UEFI mode.  Once Windows is installed copy the WinPE partition from the second drive, using your favorite third-party partition manager, to the first partition you created.  I am 90% positive this is not required, since you can literally download the ISO, from within the WinRE and the ability to reset your install exists

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to install WIndows on the same disk as Windows installation
> media

Long post and you are having problems.

Take the time to make a Windows 10 ISO and use that to install Windows and allow Windows to make the proper partitions (very especially UEFI) and have a better install.

I have done lots of Windows installs and doing it correctly pays dividends down the road.

So long as you can start the machine, just run Setup from the Windows 10 USB Key.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using this kind of installation medium creators, especially in this case, since often they do unnecessary stuff and make the whole drive occupied.

Use `wipefs` and `gdisk` to clean up a bit what had been done on the HDD, then partition the drive manually with `gdisk` by creating a 6GiB or so partition at the end** of the drive, with type code `0700` (i.e. `Microsoft Basic Data`) in `gdisk`.

Then format the partition with `mkfs.ntfs -f` and mount both the filesystem and the ISO. Copy the content under the ISO mountpoint to the NTFS mountpoint.

Now you can reboot and choose to boot from the HDD on the UEFI boot menu and start the installation.

**If you have this "installation partition" at the beginning, and your UEFI firmware does not have multi-ESP-on-single-drive support, you'll need to use e.g. `wipefs` to destroy the filesystem on the partition in order to boot the Windows installation from the UEFI boot menu. If all you care about is booting it from grub, then it shouldn't cause any problem (until you lose your grub somehow someday).

---

In reality Microsoft-domination™ has made sure that most if not all UEFI firmware available on the market have NTFS driver. The only firmware I've seen that does not is (vanilla) [EDK2/OVMF](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2). If your machine happens to have firmware that is as "pure" as that, you can still use (the existing) grub boot from the prepared "installation partition".

While you are still on the grub menu, press `c` to enter grub shell, then run:

```
search -u $serial -s
```

where `$serial` would be replaced with the volume serial of the NTFS you prepared, which would be listed as its UUID in `lsblk -f`, **or**:

```
set root=(hdX,gptY)
```

in which case `ls` can be used to to check which `hdX` has only one `gptY`, assuming the HDD is the only drive that has one partition.

Then run:

```
chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
boot
```

It should then boot to Windows Setup.